# Upload a local file to a Facebook page using curl PHP

Tags: php, curl

Actually I'm able to upload a file from a http url to my Facebook page with this code:

```
        $data = array();

        $data['url'] = "http://www.example.com/image.jpg";
        $data['access_token'] = $fb_page_access_token;

        $post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_graph_version.'/'.$fb_page_id.'/photos';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

        $return = curl_exec($ch);
```

Now I need to change this code, sending a photo from local memory of pc. For example a file called "test.jpg" inside the same dir of the script, but I don't find any example on facebook doc about the name to use. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads/

Any suggestions how to change my curl request for local files?

Comment: If your script is online, you can upload the file to your server, create a temporary URL, and send this URL to facebook as you actually do.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/#upload - you just need to provide an actual file upload with your request. (How to upload files with cURL, easily researchable.) The parameter name does not really matter, according to docs - use `source`, or something else that doesn’t collide with any of the defined parameter names.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP no my script run as local client pc with wamp server